# How to fix this issue 'TimeoutException' is not defined in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Everyone.
I hope you are going well.
I have one problem to **scrape** the data from a specific URL.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1200, 800)
driver.get(DEGIRO_URL)
loginUsername = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='username']")
loginPassword = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='password']")
loginBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
loginUsername.send_keys(LOGIN_USERNAME)
loginPassword.send_keys(LOGIN_PASSWORD)
loginBtn.click()
try:
   myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
            "//button[@class='duvfw-AB']")))
   myElem.click()
   print ("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print ("Loading took too much time!")
```

When I run this code this shows me the following issues.

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51297/devtools/browser/bf64f196-95fe-4df6-8ac8-2761849a317b
[19408:18516:0615/034317.403:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [03:43:17.403] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1072 Getting Default Adapter failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Work\scraping\scrape.py", line 83, in main
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='duvfw-AB']")))
  File "C:\Users\SingSong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Work\scraping\scrape.py", line 147, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\Work\scraping\scrape.py", line 86, in main
    except TimeoutException:
NameError: name 'TimeoutException' is not defined
```

If you have experience in this field, Please help me.
Best Regards.

Comment: Have you imported it from the selenium module?

Comment: Yes, I have imported all library.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import requests
import lxml.html
import time
import json

Comment: then you have missed importing the exception, please see my answer to fix the issue

Comment: Where can I see your answers?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you have not imported the exception from the selenium module,

simply import it by

`from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException`

Comment: I have see this answer and insert this to my code.

Comment: This is working but I can't click the button.

Comment: Loading took too much time!
I see this message.